# Rectangle Intersection. print message for empty intersection

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, procedure, rectangles

I have four coordinates: x,y,width=w,height=h and I have two rectangles with the following coordinates:

```
r1.x=2,r1.y=3,r1.w=5,r1.h=6; 
r2.x=0, r2.y=7,r2.w=-4,r4.h=2
```

How you can observe this intersection is empty.

what I did until now it was:

```
rectangle intersection (rectangle r1, rectangle r2){
r1.x=max(r1.x,r2.x);
r1.y=max(r1.y,r2.y);
r1.w=min(r1.w,r2.w);
r1.h=min(r1.h,r2.h);
return r1;
}
```

I think the above code it is used when there is an intersection, but when the intersection is empty I do not know. Also, I would like to print a message "empty" when there is no intersection.

thanks!

Comment: Unless the code you show is some [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) then please tag your question with the language you use. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and I also suggest you read [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Sometimes it helps to draw it out on paper. Checking for no intersection is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using for rectangle intersection *does NOT work* when rectangles are represented with their width and height.

It could work if you store the rectangles' two opposite corners (instead of one corner and the dimensions) and make sure that the first corner's coordinates are always less than or equal to the second corner, effectively storing `min_x`, `min_y`, `max_x`, and `max_y` for your rectangles.

I would suggest that you adopt the convention of making sure the rectangles always *include* their `min` coordinates and always *exclude* their `max` coords.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something not very different from:

```
struct rectangle {
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
};
```

(or the same using `float` or `double` instead of `int`)

I will assume here that `w` and `h` are always positive, if they may be negative, you should first normalize the input rectangle to ensure that they are.

You find the intersection by finding its opposite corners, and ensuring that lower left come before upper right:

```
rectangle intersection(const rectangle& r1, const rectangle& r2) {
    // optionaly control arguments:
    if (r1.w < 0 || r1.h < 0 || r2.w < 0 || r2.h < 0) {
        throw std::domain_error("Unnormalized rectangles on input");
    }
    int lowx = max(r1.x, r2.x);    // Ok, x coordinate of lower left corner
    int lowy = max(r1.y, r2.y);    // same for y coordinate

    int upx = min(r1.x + r1.w, r2.x + r2.w)  // x for upper right corner
    int upy = min(r1.y + r1.h, r2.y + r2.h)  // y for upper right corner

    if (upx < lowx || upy < lowy) {      // empty intersection
        throw std::domain_error("Empty intersection");
    }
    return rectangle(lowx, lowy, upx - lowx, upy - lowy);
}
```

You can normalize a rectangle by forcing positive values for width and height:

```
rectangle& normalize(rectangle& r) {
    if (r.w < 0) {
        r.x += r.w;
        r.w = - r.w;
    }
    if (r.h < 0) {
        r.y += r.h;
        r.h = -r.h;
    }
    return r;
}
```

You can then use that in a second function to display the intersection result:

```
void display_intersection(std::outstream out, rectangle r1, rectangle r2) {
    try {
        rectangle inter = intersection(normalize(r1), normalize(r2));
        out << "(" << inter.x << ", " << inter.y << ") to (";          
        out << inter.x + inter.w << ", " << inter.y + inter.h << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    except (std::domain_error& e) {
        out << "empty" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! It makes sens what you told me about canonicalize. I have another question if it possible. Can I split rectangle intersection in the following way?
1. I want rectangle intersection to do only the intersection and then 
2. create a function called PrintTheRectangle which will output when the intersection is empty and when it is not empty should output intersection from (x,y) to (w,h). 
    printf("(%d,%d) to (%d,%d)\n", r.x, r.y,
                            r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height);